# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 4, saw 19 - not sure why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file. The **first 5 lines of the CSV file** looks like this:

```
subjectGroup    browser version screenWidth screenHeight    OS  OS_lang GMT_timestamp   local_timestamp trial_file_version  mindsCode   link    duration_s                      
62  Chrome  109.0.0.0   1360    768 Windows en-GB   2023-01-29_12:15:31 2023-01-29_12:15:31 2023-01-24_14:32:48 M878637 https://www.testable.org/experiment/9943/367419/start?participant=M878637   679.84                      
                                                                        
rowNo   type    head    body    responseRows    responseType    required    pageBreak   responseOptions responseOther   trialText   stim1   stimFormat  subjectGroup    button1 timestamp   response    RT  responseCode
64  test                                    This is your unique ID for the Sea Hero Quest game.<br> Please make a note of it as you will need it to play the game.  3WMF89VV    word    62  Next    32492   1   19275   
91  form    Please answer the following question BEFORE starting the game: How good are you at navigating?          likert  1   1   very good;good;bad;very bad                         47203   very good   5697    1
```

I am trying to **extract data from a particular cell in this CSV file**, specifically the code **'M607538'** in the cell below the cell that says 'mindsCode'.'

I have the following line of code.

```
newdata2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Desktop/SavedSHQdatafullgame/demoresults/'+filename)
```

However, this gives me the error: **'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 4, saw 19'**.

If I try the following, and **skip the first 3 rows**, it works fine:

```
rows_to_keep = [0,1,2]
newdata = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Desktop/SavedSHQdatafullgame/demoresults/'+filename,skiprows = lambda x: x in rows_to_keep)
```

However, the code I want to extract is on the 2nd row, and so I want to **keep the data in the first 3 rows**. I therefore tried the following:

```
newdata2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Desktop/SavedSHQdatafullgame/demoresults/'+filename,sep='delimiter',header=None)    
newdata2.transpose()
```

However, this resulted in my data appearing in a format that made it difficult for me to extract that particular code.

[image]

I would be so grateful for a helping hand as to how I can extract the information I want! :)

Comment: Please, share the first 5 lines of your csv file as **raw text**.

Comment: Have done so :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this using the **'str.split()'** function. This separated the data into columns using the comma as a separator.

The **newer.iloc[1]** refers to me selecting the 2nd row of the data as this is what I am interested in.

I could then extract the code I wanted based on its index location in the resulting list **'here2'** that was produced.

```
newdata2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/macbook/Desktop/SavedSHQdatafullgame/demoresults/'+filename,sep='delimiter',header=None)    
newer = newdata2.transpose()
newer = newdata2.iloc[:,0].str.split(',')
here2 = newer.iloc[1]
here2[10]
```